# Compiling error "Expected [ or = " in Jack language. Where in the line is the error and why?

Tags: compiler-errors

The goal is to insert a number in order into a linked list. 
I wrote the code based on my knowledge in C. I don't know a lot of the syntax in Jack. I tried to search information, but I couldn't find anything helpful.

```
In List.jack (line 41): In subroutine insertInOrder: Expected [ or =
```

The method contains:

```
class List {
    field int data;
    field List next;

    /* Creates a new List object. */
    constructor List new(int car, List cdr) {
        let data = car;
        let next = cdr;
        return this;

    /* Inserts the argument in the right position of the list (ascending order)*/
    method void insertInOrder(int ins){
        var List prev, curr, insert;
        let prev = this;
        let curr = prev.next();
        while (ins > prev.data()){
            if (ins < curr.data()){
                let insert = List.new(ins, curr);
                let prev.next() = insert;
            }
            else{
                let prev = prev.next();
                let curr = prev.next();
            }
        }
        return;
    }
```

and the problem is in the line:

```
let prev.next() = insert;
```

How can I understand the error?

Comment: I don't know this language, but I assume that `prev.next()` is a method call on an object that returns a value. You can't assign a returned value to a value - you have to assign a variable or a property to a value.

Comment: Is the `next` property public? If so you could do `prev.next = ...` and that would work. If it is not public then you would need a setter inside `List`.

Comment: That makes sense. "next" should be a pointer just like in C if I am not mistaken. Before, I just wrote "prev.next", then I got the error saying "( is expected", so I added the "()"after "prev.next". That fixed the error, which means it is indeed a metod call. I want to make the previous object point to the new object "insert". So I need to write a setter?

Comment: If `prev.next` cannot be done in this language (either because you can't refer to properties at all, or all properties are private) then yes, you would need a setter.

Comment: Just try `prev.next = insert` on its own though - `let` tends to be to create a variable, but you are changing an object property here.

Comment: If I let any "prev.next" or "prev.data" alone, the error "Expected ("will pop up. I tried writing an setter, it worked. But then it says that " Method List.next doesn't exist". So "prev.next()" is incorrect.

Comment: No, when you are in the setter, you want `this.next`. `List` is the class, `this` is the instance of it.

Comment: I fixed the problem! It was because the "data" and "next" are private. It was a wild guess:) I wrote getter and setter and it went well. Thanks for you help:)!

Comment: Yes, that would be correct - I mentioned that earlier! Very pleased you fixed it. While you can make the `next` property public if you wish, keeping it private and using a setter is usually nicer.